# How to mention section number in Index created by imakeidx

Tags: indexing, imakeidx

I'm trying to include an index at the end of my document using `\usepackage{imakeidx}` and the `\makeindex` and `\printindex` commands.

I would like the index to mention the section number as well, for instance:

> **37. Section 37**
>   Make a mention of the word *index*
>
> **Index**
>
> index, s37, p1

Is this possible, and if yes, how?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `xindy` as index generator, it is possible to write additional information to index file, such as the section number `s37,p100` or similar.

The relevant command is `imki@wrindexentrysplit`, the format can be specified in its 3rd argument, see the lines there.

However, `xindy` does not recognize this format initially, so there has to be an additional `xindy` module, the usage of it is specified within the `options=-M sectionindex_sectionpage.xdy` option to `\makeindex`.

I used a `forloop` to generate some dummy sections with dummy index entries, just for convenience. The index shows the format `s{sectionnumber},p{pagenumber}`
.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{blindtext}%
\usepackage{fmtcount}%
\usepackage{forloop}% 

\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}%




\makeatletter
% Global redefinition of indexentry to use section, then page%
\renewcommand{\imki@wrindexentrysplit}[3]{%
 \expandafter\protected@write\csname#1@idxfile\endcsname{}%
    {\string\indexentry{#2}{s\arabic{section},p\thepage}}%
}%
\makeatother


\makeindex[options=-M sectionindex_sectionpage.xdy]

\begin{document}

\newcounter{loopcounter}

\forloop{loopcounter}{1}{\number\value{loopcounter} < 13}{%
\section{Section \Numberstring{loopcounter}}

\blindtext

\vspace{\baselineskip}

This is a dummy index entry to \textbf{\Numberstring{loopcounter}}\index{\Numberstring{loopcounter}}

}



\printindex


\end{document}
```

The file `sectionindex_sectionpage.xdy` contains

```
( require "tex/inputenc/latin.xdy")
( require "texindy.xdy" )
( require "page-ranges.xdy") 
( require "book-order.xdy")


( define-location-class "sectionfirstthenpages"
                        ("alpha" :sep "" "arabic-numbers" :sep "," "alpha" :sep "" "arabic-numbers" ))
```

[image]

Comment: can this be done without xindy? just using package index using makeindex. If put \label for each section and put \ref{thatsectionlabel} in index arument it works..but i have many sections in a large document

Comment: @LevanShoshiashvili: I don't know at the moment, I'll take a look later on

Comment: This seems to break linking when using `\usepackage{hyperref}`. Does anyone know of a way make both work together?