# Indextools package and custom index. (Section and any counter)

Tags: luatex, indexing, xindy

My problem is that I need to create a custom index that shows more than the page. 
Like this: Word, s.5,o.6,p.9 , where s. is section, o. a dummy counter, and p. page.

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{showidx}
\usepackage[splitindex,xindy]{indextools}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fontspec}



%\makeindex[options=-M sectionindex_sectionpage.xdy]
%\makeindex[name=foo,title=Test,options=-M sectionindex_sectionpage.xdy]

\makeindex[options=-M module.xdy]
\makeindex[name=foo,title=Test,options=-M module.xdy]

%\makeatletter
% Global redefinition of indexentry to use section, then page%
%\renewcommand{\imki@wrindexentrysplit}[3]{%
% \expandafter\protected@write\csname#1@idxfile%\endcsname{}%
  %  {\string\indexentry{#2}{s\arabic{section},o
 %\arabic{onet},p\thepage}}%
%}%
%\makeatother



\makeatletter
\def\indtl@wrindexsplit#1#2{%
\indtl@wrindexentrysplit{#1}{#2}{s\arabic{section},o\arabic{onet},p\thepage}%
\endgroup\indtl@showidxentry{#1}{#2}%
\@esphack%
}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\def\indtl@wrindexunique#1#2{%
\indtl@wrindexentryunique{#1}{#2}{s\arabic{section},o\arabic{onet},p\thepage}%
\endgroup\indtl@showidxentry{#1}{#2}%
\@esphack%
}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents*}{module.xdy}
( define-location-class "module"
                        ("alpha" :sep "" "arabic-numbers" :sep "," "alpha" :sep "" "arabic-numbers" ))
\end{filecontents*}

\newcounter{onet}


\begin{document}
\section{1}
\refstepcounter{onet}
Test1\index{Test1}
\refstepcounter{onet}
Test2\index[foo]{Test2}
\newpage
\section{1}
\refstepcounter{onet}
Test3\index{Test3}
\refstepcounter{onet}
 Tset\index{Test3!γλῶσσα}
 \refstepcounter{onet}
Test4\index[foo]{Test4}


\printindex

\printindex[foo]
\end{document}
```

I use indextools because I need compatibility with `bidi`. I tried to adapt the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187038/how-to-mention-section-number-in-index-created-by-imakeidx), but did not work... I really need to use xindy  and splitindex options.