# How to make index show chapters and sections instead of the page

Tags: indexing, imakeidx, makeindex, hyperlink

I am currently working on a logbook template to keep track of my work, and i would like to make an index of keywords encountered during my reasearch, all articles reviews are stored in an appendix (A), so basically Article 1 review (A1) Article 2 (A2) etc..

When i create my index, the keywords refer to a page automatically, is there a way to make them refer to a section instead ? so i can keep track of which article showed me a specific word, concept.

Basically, this is what i got so far.

[image]

And i would like it to look like this.

[image]

I am using the \imakeidx package.

> ```
> \usepackage{imakeidx} % For the index.
>   \makeindex[intoc,title=Index Alphabétique]
> ```

Also modified the 'root.mst' file like this

```
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "{\\textbf{"
heading_suffix "}}\\nopagebreak\n"
delim_0 " \\dotfill "
delim_1 " \\dotfill "
delim_2 " \\dotfill "
```

Comment: Also related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187038/how-to-mention-section-number-in-index-created-by-imakeidx (but that uses `xindy` instead of `imakeidx`).

Comment: Alright i see, thank you, it seems a bit tricky, thought there was a simpler option to do that