# Indexing Question Numbers

Tags: cross-referencing, indexing, appendices, imakeidx, makeindex

I'm typesetting a math book. Since the book spirals, and there are different types of questions in each assignment, I'd like a simple way to refer students to problem types.

I tried using a simple index, using the `imakeidx` package, but that only refers to the page number. Since there are at least 5 problems, this is not ideal; I want the actual problem number. My numbers do resume, and there are some 800 problems scattered across 120 pages, therefore the problem number would be most helpful.

I can envision a system of using `\label{NumOne}` after every single item, but that seems a bit too tedious, don't you think? Is there a different package or maybe even a counter that I can define to help ease this implementation?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[intoc]

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[resume] 
\item Problem\index{ProbType} 
\end{enumerate}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Which document class do you employ Please show us your code for a sample question. Is there a counter associated with the questions? If the answer is yes, how do you increment the counter? Please be specific.

Comment: It would be easier for us to answer your question if you **post a MWE that shows how you did the work manually** (possibly for a small part.) Then we just need to modify it to automate the tedious part

Comment: I am using `\documentclass{book}` along with `\usepackage{enumitem}`. My numbers are laid out quite normally:

`\begin{enumerate}[resume] \item Problem\index{ProbType} \end{enumerate}`

The `\index` at the end shows the page number, but it would be better to have the problem number.

Maybe a `\renewcommand` would help me change something in `imakeidx`?

Comment: Have you read up on previous approaches? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/616290/how-to-replace-page-numbers-by-item-numbers-in-the-index

Comment: Yes, I followed user31729's solution in the post "How to mention section number in Index created by imakeidx" and was unable to make effect the changes he had. I copied his commands, including the xindy option, writing the renewcommand, and making a new file called sectionindex_sectionpage.xdy. Nothing changed; I didn't make a for loop but that appeared to be used to get him several problems for the sake of example. [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187038/how-to-mention-section-number-in-index-created-by-imakeidx)

Comment: OK, I figured out that I had to run `texindy` on the command line; I'll go back to experimenting with this approach and see if I can't get what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Got it! I used

```
\makeatletter
% Global redefinition of indexentry to use section, then page%
\renewcommand{\imki@wrindexentrysplit}[3]{%
 \expandafter\protected@write\csname#1@idxfile\endcsname{}%
    {\string\indexentry{#2}{\arabic{enumi}}}%
}%
\makeatother
```

As I mentioned above, I followed everything laid out in user31729's solution, found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187038/how-to-mention-section-number-in-index-created-by-imakeidx). You do need to run `texindy` on the command line in order for the changes to take effect.